# How to pass a big JSON as an input to MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have a `JSON` that have 14 elements in it. something like this:

```
{ 
  "name":"fahim",
  "lastname" "morfiy"
  "phone":"0939398343",
  "nationalId": "29382383",
  .... 
}
```

I want pass this `JSON` as input to a stored procedure and insert it in MySQL. I want to insert each element in one record so that every key and value in `JSON` file insert as a one record. How can I do it?

```
id  ---> key    ----> value

1   ---> name    ---> fahim    
1   ---> last    ---> morfiy
```

Comment: If you use PHP you can try with `json_decode` and pass each params to SP

Comment: depending on your language the ways can be different, which one you are using

Comment: i use nodejs. but I think if i want to query in database for each param may be is not good. i want to pass all json and write code in a mysql procedure @ConstantinTrepadus

Comment: you can save JSON in a filed in mysql 8.0.X http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-json/ 
but indexing a json  filed is not possible you need to store index field in different column. Json in save as blob

Comment: Improved formatting and grimmer